# Initialize empty ByteArray

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How do you initialize an empty ByteArray in Kotlin? Whenever I try to do this:

```
val asdfasdf : ByteArray
```

I get told that I need to initialize asdfasdf when I try to use it later here:

```
mVisualizer.getWaveForm(asdfasdf)
```

> Variable 'asdfasdf' must be initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `val asdfasdf : ByteArray` is just declaration of immutable that needs to be initialized. If you know size in advance, you can init it like this `val asdfasdf : ByteArray = ByteArray(10)` however you probably need something like this `val asdfasdf = arrayListOf<Byte>()` to be able add items into it dynamically.

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way to make a `ByteArray` in Kotlin in my opinion is to use [`byteArrayOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/byte-array-of.html). It works for an empty `ByteArray`, as well as one which you already know the contents of.

```kotlin
val nonEmpty = byteArrayOf(0x01, 0x02, 0x03)
var empty = byteArrayOf()
empty += nonEmpty
```