# I have a problem with translate java to kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to copy a SQLite database into a project. I manage to come up with a way to do it in Java which I would like to convert into kotlin.

This is the Java part:

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

```
private void copiarBaseDatos() {
        String ruta = "/data/data/com.example.sqlite/databases/";
        String archivo = "contactos.db";
        File archivoDB = new File(ruta + archivo);
        if (!archivoDB.exists()) {
        try {
            InputStream IS = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(archivo);
            OutputStream OS = new FileOutputStream(archivoDB);
            ***byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];***
            int length = 0;
            while ((length = IS.read(buffer))>0){
                OS.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            OS.flush();
            OS.close();
            IS.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Archivo no encontrado, " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error al copiar la Base de Datos, " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

This is where I got lost.

```
fun copiarBaseDatos() {
    val ruta: String = "/data/data/com.example.sqlite/databases/";
    val archivo: String = "contactos.db";
    val archivoDB: File = File(ruta + archivo);
    if (!archivoDB.exists()) {
        try {
            val IS: InputStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(archivo);
            val OS: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(archivoDB)
            //   var buffer : byte[] = byte[1024];
            //Veré Is my problem
            ***var buffer: Byte = Byte[1024];***


            int length = 0;
            while ((length = IS.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                OS.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            OS.flush();
            OS.close();
            IS.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Archivo no encontrado, " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error al copiar la Base de Datos, " + e.toString());
        }
    }


}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Probably `ByteArray`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize empty ByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546602/initialize-empty-bytearray)

Comment: `val buffer = ByteArray(1024)`

Comment: IntelliJ has an option to convert java to kotlin.